# Деректива [routerLink] работает тогда, когда на текущей страничке присутствует router-outlet?

Tags: angular2, angular

Столкнулся с проблемой:

на странице есть кнопки с `[routerLink]="['browser', page.id]`, так вот, при нажатии на кнопку менялось лишь значение в адресной строке, но другой компонент не загружался, хотя маршрут был сопоставлен:

```
 path: 'page/:id', component: PageBrowserComponent
```

Сама страничка была такой:

```
<div>
  <app-search></app-search>
  <app-list></app-list>
</div>
```

И вот после того, как я сделал дополнительный компонент:

PageContainer, который внутри себя содержал только [routerLink] и смаршрутизировал все таким образом:

```
path: 'mainPage', component: PageContainerComponent, children: [
  {
    path: '', component: PageHomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'page/:id', component: PageBrowserComponent
  }
```

все заработало...

Собственно вопрос, [routerLink] работает тогда, когда используется router-outlet или я что-то делал не так, раз у меня не работало?

Пример вот [тут](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esimxd?embed=1&file=src/app/page/components/list/list.component.html)

**UPD:**

Хочу сделать такое поведение:

Есть router-outlet, пользователь в отображаемом представлении /page, затем что-то жмякает и переходит на page/detail/1 в этом же router-outlet и т д.

сейчас я желаемого смог достигнуть таким образом:

```
{
    path: 'page', component: PageContainerComponent, children: [
      {
        path: '', component: PageComponent
      },
      { path: 'detail/:pageId', component: DetailComponent },
      { path: 'detail/:pageId/edit', component: PageEditComponent }
    ]
  }
```

но не уверен, что это верно...

Comment: `router-outlet` это обычная директива, как и `routerLink` и между собой они никак не связаны

Comment: @overthesanity ну т.е я должен был все таки перейти в другой компонент?

Comment: добавь ссылку на [mcve]

Comment: @iluxa1810, я не знаю, я ответил на ваш вопрос - `Собственно вопрос, [routerLink] работает тогда, когда используется router-outle`

Comment: @Grundy залил в stackblitz

Comment: @iluxa1810, слушайте, ну это совсем банальные вещи, пожалуйста, читайте документацию...

Comment: @overthesanity ну хотя бы тыкните меня носом в абзац... =( Так-то фреймворк большой и документация большая...

Comment: если детально пройти [весь этот туториал](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/), то тайное станет явным

Comment: типа в компоненте подписаться на изменение маршрута и сделать программную навигацию?

Comment: @iluxa1810, вы меня как будто не слышите, я вам за одно - вы мне за другое :D

Comment: @overthesanity, ну единственное, за что зацепился глаз- это navigate...

Comment: @iluxa1810, пожалуйста, просто делайте что вам говорят в данном случае :D в том туториале есть разделы, который вам нужно проделать ручками у себя локально и вы поймете в чем ошибка, я то ошибку вижу, но называть ее - так неинтересно играть) сначала фармите экспу и поднимаете уровень, а с читами это не то))

Comment: @overthesanity под разделы в разделе Routing?

Comment: @iluxa1810 yep.

Comment: @overthesanity ну я ничего не вижу... здаюсь.

Comment: @iluxa1810 это ужасное чувство, когда у тебя ошибка, а другой человек знает в чем ошибка и говорит "читайте доки". А ты все равно не [тупой]не видишь ошибку. Надеюсь вы все таки решили проблему)

Comment: @overthesanity, если в дочернем сделать так: const pageRoutes:Routes=[
  //{
  //   path:'page',component: ListComponent
  //   ,children:[{
  //     path:'detail/:id',component:DetailComponent
  //   }]
  // }
  {path:'page',component: AppComponent,children:[
    {
    path:'',component: ListComponent
    },   {
    path:'detail/:id',component: DetailComponent
    }
    ]}
  ];, то работает. Но я не уверен, что это верное решение

Comment: @iluxa1810 там есть раздел - child routing, в нем как раз и ответ. Ищите то, что вы упустили в своем примере. Если вы сами найдете ответ, а не я вам скажу, то это +5х к собственной карме и экспе) P.S. это не связано с конфигурацией `Routes`, так что можете вернуть все как было, дело в шаблоне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ладно, так как вы потратили достаточно количество времени на изучение этого вопроса - все же оставлю ответ

В туториале, который я вам скинул на самом деле ответ кроется в [этом разделе](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html).

Смысл заключается в том что количество `router-outlet` директив может быть неограниченно. Роутинг у вас сконфигурирован немного неправильно, если вы хотите изолировать какую-то бизнес логику в другом модуле, то лучше использовать ленивую загрузку, но ни в коем случае не импортировать этот модуль напрямую в `AppModule`.

Конфигурация роутинга по большей части представляет из себя дерево:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждый `UrlTree` должен быть связан с директивой `router-outlet` для того, чтобы роутинг функционировал, а не просто менялись URL'ы в браузере без изменения контента. Потому что за рендеринг компонента, который объявлен в свойстве `component` отвечает именно директива `router-outlet`.

`UrlTree`  —  это структура данных внутри Angular, которая предоставляет множество фичей для работы с URL адресами. `UrlTree` состоит из `UrlSegmentGroup`, которая в свою очередь состоит из `UrlSegment`. `UrlSegment`  —  это строка между двумя слешами в URL’е. Как раз таки `UrlSegment`  —  это обертка поверх свойства `path` в наших конфигурациях.

На картинке, приведенной выше, по пути `/` Angular загрузит ленивый модуль `HomeModule` у которого также есть такая же конфигурация, например:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

export const HomeRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule> = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Это сработает и директива `router-outlet`, которая находится в шаблоне `AppComponent` отрендерит компонент `HomeComponent`. Вот только у этого модуля может быть также дочерний роутинг:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'about',
      loadChildren: './pages/about/about.module#AboutModule'
    }
  ]
}
```

Если мы в браузере перейдем по пути `/about` - то Angular загрузит `AboutModule`, но мы ничего не увидим, потому что родительская директива `router-outlet` отвечает за рендеринг только первых дочерних компонентов (`HomeComponent`), для того, чтобы мы увидели контент по пути `/about` - нам нужно добавить еще одну директиву `router-outlet` в `home.component.html`, и тогда именно эта директива будет нести ответственность за рендеринг первого дочернего компонента. У модуля `AboutModule` также может быть свой дочерний роутинг:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: AboutComponent,
  children: [
    path: 'member/:name',
    loadChildren: './pages/member/member.module#MemberModule'
  ]
}
```

Перейдя по пути `/about/member/iluxa` мы не увидим контент. Что мы делаем? Правильно, добавляем еще одну директиву `router-outlet` в `about.component.html`.

Возвращаясь к вашему примеру - нужно добавить директиву `router-outlet` в `list.component.html` и тогда по пути `/page/detail/1` мы увидим `detail works!`.

P.S. - кстати, не биндите значение входного параметра директивы `routerLink` через квадратные скобки + массив, лучше используйте интерполяцию, она удобнее + весьма читабельнее:

```
<div><a routerLink="detail/{{ 3 }}" routerLinkActive="active"> 3</a></div>
```

С тройкой я конечно тут перебрал, интерполяция не нужна, но если например вам нужно отрендерить список ссылок, то используйте интерполяцию вместо массива:

```
<a *ngFor="let link of links" routerLink="/dashboard/categories/{{ link.url }}">{{ link.label }}</a>
```

Comment: А можете приложить еще исправленный stackblitz?

Comment: @iluxa1810 если я правлю ваш stackblitz и нажимаю share то у меня копируется ссылка на ваш источник без сохранения изменений :( просто добавьте `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` после ссылок в `list.html`

Comment: я еще вопрос малость дополнил.

Comment: у вас урлы в вопросе и конфигурации не совпадают, приводите в пример урл такой же какой вы указываете в `Routes`, потому что это полностью сбивает с толку

Comment: конфигурации на stackblitz?

Comment: @iluxa1810, нет, просто вы в вопросе пишите `затем что-то жмякает и переходит на page/number/1` ------> `page/number/1`, а в роутах у вас `page/detail/:pageId/edit`, это меня сбивает с толку очень :)

Comment: ок,. поправил..

Comment: @iluxa1810, так в чем ваш вопрос, просто в конце я увидел `но не уверен, что это верно...` =D

Comment: Можно ли так делать или это плохой тон?

Comment: можно, но по нормальному деревья роутов должны начинаться с пустого пути `{ path: '', component: PageComponent }`, а путь `page` должен быть определен на верхнем уровне, но раз уже это работает, то так и оставляйте. Начинайте изучать ленивую загрузку

Comment: @iluxa1810 у вас еще есть вопросы?)

Comment: Сделайте пример на стекблизе, я получу экспириенс и приму ваш ответ.;)

Comment: @iluxa1810, ок, с какими роутами?

Comment: По моему последнему upd. Хочу познать до конца дзен, как правильно это делается.

Comment: Т,е есть один роут аутлет в котором что то отображается. При переходе по ссылке я хочу перерисовать этот родительский аутлет новым содержимым. Был на маршруте page, нажал на кнопку и попал на page/detail/3 , там что то жмякнул и попал на page/detail/3/super info/100500. И все это в одном аутлет

Comment: @iluxa1810 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vz9ncj

Comment: Немного не то... Вы details отображаете в дочернем аутлете, а я хотел, что бы при клике по описанию, эта инфа не появлялась ниже, а полностью собою замещала "Текущий герой: бла бла бла". Ну или услышать, что так делать нельзя.

Comment: @iluxa1810 нельзя

Comment: Во, вот это я и хотел услышать. А то что-то ковырял ковырял и не смог добиться повторно использования родительского маршрута=(